# Actions on Google Transactions Authorization URL domain name consistency

Tags: actions-on-google

Does the authorization URL domain name have to be the same as the webhook url domain used with API.ai?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: They can be different or same it's up to you.

Longer one: Authorization URL for account linking is completely separate from API.ai, the only thing it does is to allow you to have a token sent with every request you make from actions-on-google, other than that it's not linked anyhow to api.ai. so you can have same domain name, different one it's up to you, you can even make account linking and not use api.ai but make your own NLP instead.